# Is it possible to forbid annotation inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations

I have a controller superclass and its subclass:

```
public class SuperController {
    @Resource
    private A resourceA;
}

public class SubController extends SuperController {
    @Resource
    private B resourceB;
}
```

I don't use `resourceA` field in `Subcontroller`, but `Subcontroller` acts as `SuperController` and has the same methods. So how can I forbit the inheritance of `@Resource` annotation, just like that:

```
public class SuperController {
    **private** @Resource
    private A resourceA;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a common abstract class if the sub-class doesn't use some of the fields of the parent class.

```
public abstract class AbstractController {
    // common fields.
    // common methods.
}

public class SuperController extends AbstractController {
    @Resource
    private A resourceA;
}

public class SubController extends AbstractController {
    @Resource
    private B resourceB;
}
```